# I have a weird problem with tkinter when using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to use Tkinter, but whenever I want to execute my code I always get this problem: (NameError: name 'label' is not defined) or (NameError: name 'button' is not defined).

As a beginner, it seems to me that the problem is with my code editor. (BTW I am using VScode)

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mylabel = label(root, text='Hello World')
mylabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And as I said, this also happens with this one:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mybutton = button(root, text='Hello World')
mybutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The tkinter classes are `Button` and `Label`, not `button` and `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have caps error its  Button and Label not button and label

Comment: I can't believe I was stuck on that! Thanks to everyone that responded.